# Github commit listener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, listener, capistrano

I was wondering if there was some kind of built in gem or API that Github has that allows me to have a listener that detects when someone commits to a repository. The reason for this is because I am using Capistrano and would like to call cap production deploy when someone changes the repository and automatically change the users local machine.

Thank in advance,

Troy Reynolds

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitHub's WebHooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to have github call a URL of your choosing when a push is received.

You could write a lightweight sinatra application on your deployment server that would call capistrano for you when it receives the webhook call.

Comment: Thanks! I can't vote up your answer I do not have enough points but thanks. I will try this out.

Comment: @user3758142 You still should mark it as correct if it helped.